# PostGIS via GeoDjango: function ST_DistanceSphere(geometry, geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I've been using PostGIS via GeoDjango (Django v3.0.7), happily until just now.  I have a query (Django `.filter()`) that looks like this:

```
.filter(point__distance_lte=(dlPt, D(m=CloseRadius)))
```

when it invokes the PostgreSQL query I get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function ST_DistanceSphere(geometry, geometry) does not exist
```

`dlPt` is indeed a Point, `<class 'django.contrib.gis.geos.point.Point'>`, and so are the `point` attributes in the objects being searched.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Have you created PostGIS extension in the database?

Comment: If created, what version of PostGIS are you using?

Comment: [Looks like](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#distance-lte) `distance_lte` uses `ST_Distance_Sphere` (note the `_`; not sure if typo, though), which is deprecated in PostGIS 3.x. Test with direct SQL; if that's the case, it's tivial to write a wrapper function. Also, if possible, use `dwithin` (it calls the index driven `ST_DWithin`, which is _much_ faster).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function **st_distancesphere** is avaialble for PostGIS version 2.2 and greater. So make sure that while using PostGIS with Geodjango it has a version that is greater then 2.2, otherwise it won't be able to find it in the database.

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html

And you can check your PostGIS version by using this query

```
SELECT PostGIS_Version();
```

Comment: yup, that was it!  SELECT PostGIS_Version() returns: "2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1".  thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!